# Strange 'Parameter is not valid' problem in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, gdi+

I have created a custom control in Winforms. I can put one of these controls on a form, resize it and run it with no problem. I can create a second instance of the control on the same form, resize both, run it, no problem. I can stop it from running, resize both controls, run it, no problem. When I remove the second control however, if I try to resize the first control, I get a message box appearing with 'Parameter is not valid.'.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what the problem could be?

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: It's over 1400 lines, which is why I didn't share it. I don't expect anybody to try and debug all that, just hoping someone might have some inkling as to what may be the problem. 
Anyway, I think I've found the solution, I was disposing of a font in the Dispose method, which appears to be the problem.

Comment: Yo can share only a part with problem, as well as error stack trace

Comment: Something isn't being disposed of and or `null` and it probably should be. Are you doing any drawing in this custom control; painting etc.? Without code, how are we able to replicate your issue and help you?

Comment: For future reference StackOverflow posts need to have a minimal reproducible example. StackOverflow is for fixing code, nothing else. If we dont have code we cant help you and really shouldn't try to.

Comment: Yes, I was disposing of a Font that I had created incorrectly, removing this line has solved the problem. @Pavel Apologies, I'm still relatively new to C# and the error message gave me no indication as to which area the problem was in. The message was literally 'Parameter is not valid', that was it, no line numbers, method calls or anything to point me to where to look.